# How to understand whether client connected to server in c#?

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, network-programming

I am trying to make connection between a client and a server using sockets. I have a GUI for this. Here is my code:

This is the code for the server, it takes the port number from a textbox in the gui, and when start button is clicked, a socket is created.

```
Thread thrAccept;
Socket server_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
Socket n;

private void button_start_listening_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox_server_activity_log.AppendText("Server started. Waiting for clients... \n");
    button_start_listening.Enabled = false;
    server_socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Convert.ToInt32(textbox_port_no.Text)));

    server_socket.Listen(100);
    thrAccept = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Accept));
    thrAccept.Start();

}

private void Accept()
{
    n = server_socket.Accept();            
}
```

And for the client, i have enter the ip and port numbers from the users using two textboxes and click the connect button, and to establish connection, i use this piece of code:

```
c.Connect(ipText.Text, Convert.ToInt32(portText.Text)); //c is a socket
```

My question is, when the connection is established, i want to print something like "Client connected" in the GUI of the server. But how can i let server know that client has connected?

Thank you

Comment: What is your issue though? The `Socket.Accept` method blocks until it can accept a connection from a remote host. Therefore, at the end of your `Accept` method you can say "Client Connected".. because at that point it has accepted a connection.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead thank you, i did not know that it blocks until it accepts a connection, i will try it

Comment: That's why you've had to put it in it's own Thread.. your UI would have been unresponsive otherwise.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead just one more quick question: I also have a textbox in client's GUI that clients enter a username. How can i pass this username parameter to the server so that the server also displays the connected client's username? I keep the client and server GUI's in separate projects

Comment: You can't in a single burst. Initially the socket will accept the connection - which comes with the remote hosts IP/hostname, etc. After that, you need to send a request to the client for their username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
   private void Accept()
    {
        try {
            n = server_socket.Accept();
            richTextBox_server_activity_log.AppendText("Connection Established...");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            richTextBox_server_activity_log.AppendText("Failed to Connect...");
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks, but instead of Console.Writeline, i handle the message in gui's richtextbox

Comment: This method is run in a separate Thread. Using the RichTextBox like this will likely throw a Cross-Thread exception.